# TestFlight: Invalid Profile: distribution build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to false

Tags: bash, xcode5, testflight

After looking through various other ideas here and elsewhere, I still have yet to find an answer to this. I believe it has something to do with the way I'm building the command in the bash script, but I'm  not sure. It builds and archives as I would expect, but then when I try to upload to TestFlight, bad things happen. I call TestFlight via curl after the code below.

```
xcodebuild -target ${PROJ_NAME} -configuration "Ad Hoc"
xcodebuild archive -project "${PROJ_NAME}.xcodeproj" -scheme ${SCHEME_NAME} -configuration "Ad Hoc"

cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
cd ${ARCH_FOLDER}
LATEST_FILE=`ls -rt | tail -1`
cd "$LATEST_FILE/Products/Applications"

xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v ${APP_NAME} -o ${IPA_LOC}/${IPA_NAME}
```